# Cpanel email addresses failure connected to Google Domains

Tags: email, cpanel, google-domains

I have a domain name with Google Domains and I'm using cPanel. When I create an email address in cpanel and send an email to that address, it's saying it doesn't exist. Somehow, it's connected to Google still how can I fix this problem and use the email address I created in cPanel? I'm getting this when I send an email to the cPanel address I made.

> Address not found
>
> Your message wasn't delivered to email@site.org because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.

The response from the remote server was:

> 550 5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser u7-20020a170902e5c700b0019a849a40b8si99644plf.6 - gsmtp

Comment: Where are the nameservers pointing?  That is the place where DNS is being managed.  When you look at DNS, where are the MX Records pointing?  That is where email is being handled.  I suspect that your MX records aren't set up properly.

Comment: I got it thanks for the help i had to delete the MX on google.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the nameservers pointing? That is the place where DNS is being managed.

When you look at DNS, where are the MX Records pointing? That is where email is being handled.

I suspect that your MX records aren't set up properly.   Check the MX records at Google